# Failed Ubuntu Touch install on Oneplus 6

Tags: porting-ubuntu-touch

My Oneplus 6 is unlocked and in Developer mode, TWRP was run and installed. Everything was ready to flash Touch. I am on a Macbook with Ubuntu installed so I downloaded the Ubuntu (deb) download. I ran the download and connected the 1+6 and everything looked good, 1+6 was recognized, and the install process appeared almost complete, and then I received an error. I retried 3 times and received the error. Finally, the phone seemed stuck on the screen saying the bootloader was unlocked yada yada. I finally was able to get the 1+6 back into FastBoot Mode. When I try to rerun the Ubports installer it does not recognize the 1+6. The phone is now showing the Product_Name - sdm845. The Installer identifies that as the device. I tried self-selecting Oneplus 6 and run install and it errors off right away saying device is not recognized. I can't seem to get anywhere with the phone.
This is the error I receive:
Error: adb:preparesystemimage: Error: {“error”:{“code”:1,”cmd”:”adb -P 5037 shell mkdir -p /cache/recovery”},”stderr”:”mkdir: ‘/cache/recovery’: Required key not available”}

Comment: Is Ubuntu Touch discontinued?
Ubuntu Mobile Internet Device Edition is a discontinued Ubuntu distribution planned to run on the Intel Mobile Internet Device platform, x86 mobile computers based on the Intel Atom processor.

Comment: Oneplus 6 is not on the list of supported devices of UBPorts. Therefore, you will have to port it and this is no trivial task.

Comment: This was resolved by using an older UbPorts installer (0.8.8) version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: I had to remove the most current updated stabile installer and use an older version (0.8.8). The recommendation was made by another person and it worked!